# Data to separate view controller not working

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

So I'm trying to pass data from a cell to a different view controller, and while I do get back the value inside "user3" when I try to transport it over to "user2" I don't get any value. I have tried to print user2 and didn't get back anything and neither any errors. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the "func prepare" but I can't figure out what.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"searchCell", for: indexPath)
    as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.titleField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption
    cell.userUID?.text = posts[indexPath.row].uid
    cell.descriptionField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].description
    cell.tagsField?.text = posts[indexPath.row].tags
    let photoUrl = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl
    let url = URL(string: photoUrl)
    cell.SearchImage.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil)
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! CustomTableViewCell
    let currentItem = currentCell.userUID!.text
    var user3: String = ""
    user3.append(currentItem!)



func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? userViewController {
            destinationViewController.user2 = user3
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related but don't do `let currentItem = currentCell.userUID!.text`, Don't rely on the UI, rely on your model. Instead `let currentItem = posts[indexPath.row].uid`.

Comment: For your issue, disconnect the Segue you created from the `UITableViewCell` to the `userViewController`. Instead do it from the `ViewController1` to the `userViewController`, and in `didSelectRowAt` call yourself the segue with `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierOfTheSegue" sender:nil)` (or something like that). If you check correctly with logs/breakpoints, you should notice then that `prepare(for segue)` is called before `didSelectRowAt` in your current case.

Comment: ... and make sure `prepare(for:sender)` is a top level method and not defined inside of another.

Comment: how do I make the didSelectRow run before the segue?

Comment: didSelectRow run before "prepare(for segue)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to forget `didSelectRowAt` and connect the segue to the prototype cell in Interface Builder rather than to the view controller.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as! CustomTableViewCell
    let currentItem = currentCell.userUID!.text
    var user3: String = ""
    user3.append(currentItem!)
}
```

Then `prepare(for segue` is called passing the table view cell in the sender parameter

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? userViewController,
            let cell = sender as? CustomTableViewCell,
            let indexPath =  tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
               let currentUID = posts[indexPath.row].uid
               destinationViewController.user2 = currentUID
        }
    }
}
```

Get always the data from the **model** (the data source array), not from the **view** (the cell)

Comment: This does seem to work, however I can't click on any cell anymore. Do I need to do something else except copying your code? XD

Comment: Nevermind I missed the segue connect in your answer.